# Premake5 will not run on Mac OS

Tags: premake

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi6As.png)

I tried to run the premake5 file retrieved from https://premake.github.io/download.html
But bash gives me this. Not sure what is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Premake is a command line application; [here is an article](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line) on what that means, and how to use the macOS Terminal application.